# Dashboard Designer KPI Trend over time (compared to previous quarter) - using excel services

Tags: 2010, performancepoint

I can't seem to get a trend to work correctly in my KPI.  I want to compare it to the previous quarter, but all I keep getting is the sum of the quarter, rather than the previous value.  I basically want to compare the quarter's value to the previous quarter's value, and just display an up arrow if more, a down arrow if less, and a straight arrow if about the same.

This is my data:

```
Date        Category    Number of Users
01/04/2012  Staff   10
01/07/2012  Staff   20
01/10/2012  Staff   100
01/01/2013  Staff   5000
```

The time column looks set correctly in the datasource properties, and I am using an excel services datasource.
Here's the time config:
[image: Time Configuration]

Whenever I try to create the Trend part it just sums up, rather than comparing only to the previous quarter, so I assume I'm just getting the time intelligence filter wrong.

I have the Actual set to the actual, which displays fine per quarter.

The Trend is compared to Actual, as shown here:
[image: KPI Trend Properties]

It seems to be adding up rather than dynamically referring tot he previous quarter, as shown here:
[image]

I basically want to compare the quarter's value to the previous quarter's value, and just display an up arrow if more, a down arrow if less, and a straight arrow if about the same.  I thought it would be easy, but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Can we see your Time Intelligence configuration?

Comment: Time config screen now added.

Answer (score 1):

(Just incase you never figured this out, or if someone else stumbles across this post with a similar issue) - in dashboard designer, open your data source, and click the view tab.  Each column being mapped has an aggregation type, by default set to SUM.  Change the aggregation to None.